# Windows 10 - can not change default program of file

Tags: windows, java

I'm using Windows 10 and I wanted .pie files to be opened with a jar file I created, so I used assoc and ftype as follows:

```
assoc .pie PieLang
ftype PieLang=java -jar pielang.jar "%1"
```

`assoc .pie` does return `.pie = PieLang`, and ftpe PieLang does return `PieLang=java -jar pielang.jar "%1"`, so everything should work.

However, everytime I open a .pie file, no matter if I do it using double click or using CMD, it will always open with Notepad.

Is there any way I can fix that?

EDIT: Now I can't change .py files either. But somehow pdf files it does let me change

EDIT2: It doesn't work on file properties as well. Instead, when I choose a program as default on the menu, it opens on that program one time, but it doesn't change the default

EDIT3: Ramhound's solution doesn't work as I said before.

(Asked in StackOverflow and my question was marked "on hold" and they told me to post my question here, so I did)

Comment: SuperUser is definitely the place to ask this, so you got that part sorted. If you select the file in explorer, then right-click -> open with -> other program -> check always open this program and select the right program, does that work? Can you associate it with anything else at all?

Comment: @LPChip It doesn't work either apparently

Comment: @Ramhound What do you mean it's a known issue? Windows just let this issue stay as it is?

Comment: @Ramhound I don't understand what do you mean, I am pretty new to all this stuff, Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: The bug is known and will be fixed in a future patch.

Answer (score -1):

if you have associeted your file .pie opens automatically with another program, then you have to do : go in settings->system and search app default for type file.(Here you can solve the problem)

Sorry uf the name is different but i have italian language and i don't know which is tne real name on windows 10 in english...
i hope this help you

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but it's not my problem :)